# What does the notation $\| \cdot \|_p^q$ mean?

Tags: real-analysis, notation

This is used in my analysis book (Royden) when proving containment of $L^p$ spaces. Specifically the context is,

If you take $1\leq p <q < \infty,$ the proof in the book implies that from Holder's inequality that

$$ \|f\|_{q/p} = \|f\|_q^p,$$

I have not previously seen this notation in the book and am wondering what this means and where it comes from.

Thanks!

Comment: The equality is not true. Did you mis-quote the text? The right side is $(\|f\|_q)^{p}$.

Comment: No this was just my understanding of what the proof in the book was implying by using this notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\|f\|_q^p$ is just a compact way of writing $(\|f\|_q)^p$ where $\|f\|_q$ is defined in the usual way i.e. $\|f\|_q = \left(\int |f(x)|^q \, dx \right)^{1/q}$,
so $\|f\|_q^p = \left(\int |f(x)|^q \, dx \right)^{p/q}$.

On the other hand, $\|f\|_{q/p} = \left(\int |f(x)|^{q/p}\right)^{p/q}$.